# How to change value and re-trigger eventListener in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a public chat app using Firebase Real-time Database, but stuck on this problem. Like normal chat apps, I am displaying only few texts to the user and when/if the user scrolls the List is updated and more messages are displayed.

I have a listener to my Firebase reference, which is only displaying (say 10 messages):

```
int j = 10;
 myRef.child("Chat").limitToLast(j).addChildEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
         //   Map<String,Object> datemsg = (Map<String,Object>)dataSnapshot.getValue();

             Map<String,Object> msg = (Map<String,Object>)dataSnapshot.getValue();


                        String text = msg.get("Text").toString();
                        values.add(text);


        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Now I have a scroll Listener that changes the value for `j` to `j+10` but then the ChildEvenListener is not triggered and the new messages are not added to the listview.

I also tried using queries, but again having the same problem, after updating the value, how should I update the adapter?

No new child is added, thus the childevent listener is not triggered, but I want to change the size of

```
limitToLast(j)
```

and re-populate the list. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase queries are immutable. If you change the value you pass into `limitToLast()`, it becomes a new query.

So you must attach a new listener to the new query, and then repopulate the list with the items from that listener.

If you keep track of the key (`dataSnapshot.getKey()`) for each existing item in your list, you can optimize the updating of the list by checking if each item from the new listener is already present in the list.

Comment: Ohh I see. I though there might be another way to achieve it instead of adding a listener again. Now that I have a direction I can move forward. Thank you sir for your time.

Comment: One more thing I am confused about is, if we can pass int values as parameters to startAt() or endAt() to point out the exact number of node in that child?

Comment: If you have the *key* of the item you want to start at, you can pass that in as the second argument to `startAt()`. But this is a parameter that is frequently misunderstood by developers, so ymmv.