# Firebase Database filtering with dynamic value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am filtering Firebase database data using `endAt` filter for a child key value like so:

```
  database.ref('events').orderByChild('startTime').endAt(new Date().getTime()).on('value', (snapshot) => {
    console.log('SNAPSHOT VALUE: ', snapshot.val())
  })
```

However, when the data changes at events node, the `endAt` filter still uses the `oldDate().getTime()`, not the current value of time. And if I update the variable in the callback function and use that as the value for the `endAt` filter, it will use that the next time the data changes, in which case, the value for time will be outdated again.

So how can I use a current time in the filter when there is an event trigger? Or is the only option that I pull all the events and filter it in the client?

Code from comment:

```
database.ref('events').orderByChild('startTime').on('value', (snapshot) => { 
    database.ref('events').orderByChild('startTime').endAt(new Date().getTime()).once('value', (snapshot) => { 
      console.log('SNAPSHOT VALUE: ', snapshot.val()) 
    }) 
}
```

**Update:**  The code from comment does work in implementing a new filter listener every time there is a change in the events tree. But to be efficient I need to implement `off()` on each of the prior listener before I create a new one.

**Update 2:** Not sure if this is an improvement, but I am turning off older listeners like so:

```
database.ref('events').orderByChild('startTime').on('value', (snapshot) => { 
    innerListener ? innerListener.off() : null
    const innerListener = database.ref('events').orderByChild('startTime').endAt(new Date().getTime()).once('value', (snapshot) => { 
      console.log('SNAPSHOT VALUE: ', snapshot.val()) 
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Firebase queries are immutable. See the answer I just gave here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825274/how-to-change-value-and-re-trigger-eventlistener-in-firebase/39832837#39832837

Comment: Thanks @puf , can you elaborate how i can attach a new listener with  the new time value. I'm i correct in thinking that this may work :                                           `database.ref('events').orderByChild('startTime').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    database.ref('events').orderByChild('startTime').endAt(new Date().getTime()).on('value', (snapshot) => {
      console.log('SNAPSHOT VALUE: ', snapshot.val())
    })
  })`            The outer listener trggers new listner at the new time in the inner listener.